# SQL How to calculate new created fields from the select statement

Tags: sql, select, subquery, case

My actually query uses a `CASE` statement to create two new columns.  I then want to take the values of those new columns and calculate the average of them.
Below is a sample, where it causes the same error of "Invalid Column Name".  What can I do to fix this?

```
select 
    1 as apples, 
    2 as pears,
    (apples + pears) as oranges
```

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 98
> Invalid column name 'apples'.
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 98
> Invalid column name 'pears'.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously that's an over-simplified example, otherwise you would just do `(1 + 2) as oranges`, right?

You can't refer to an alias defined in the `select` clause in the same scope where  it is defined (left apart the `order by` clause). A typical workaround is use a subquery:

```
select t.*, (apples + pears) as oranges
from (select 1 as apples, 2 as pears) t
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no column or expression in the select clause that has precedence over another. `1 as apples` does not necessarily happen before `(apples + pears) as oranges`. You can consider all this happening at the same moment and you cannot define and reference the alias names at the very same moment.

So either

```
select 1 as apples, 2 as pears, (1 + 2) as oranges
```

or

```
select apples, pears, (apples + pears) as oranges
from (select 1 as apples, 2 as pears) two_fruits
```